# Facebook SDK ios v4.4.0 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, handoff

I have implemented Facebook SDK in my iOS app following the Facebook guidelines and in my AppDelegate I set:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
 // more code

  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Now, I have also implemented handoff in my app and `- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application willContinueUserActivityWithType:(NSString *)userActivityType` will never be called when app starts from scratch because FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance returns false.

So my question: Is there any side effects if I don't return the result of `[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance]application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and I return my custom result? For example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
 // more code

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: I also really need answer of this question......

Comment: @agy did you got any solution for this?

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer NO.

---

`[FBSDKApplicationDelegate application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` 
method should be invoked just for the proper use of the Facebook SDK from the 
`[UIApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method
 of the AppDelegate for your app.

**This method return `YES` if the url was intended for the Facebook SDK, `NO` if not.**

---

### In latest [Facebook getting started docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) they mention it

> To post process the results from Facebook Login or Facebook Dialogs (or any action that requires switching over to the native Facebook app or Safari) you need to conenct your `AppDelegate` to the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate`. In your AppDelegate.m add:

```
//  AppDelegate.m
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
}
```